# Which solution of the two is the most efficient? Is there a better one? (IP Address Defang)

Tags: python, comparative-review

I just started doing preparation for interviews, but im having trouble recognizing the optimal solution

**Problem:** For a given IP Address, replace every "." with "[.]"

**Example:**

```
Input: address = "1.1.1.1"
Output: "1[.]1[.]1[.]1"
```

**My solutions:**

**First:**

```
def defang(x):
    lst = []
    for i in x:
        if i == ".":
             lst.append("[" + i + "]")
        else:
            lst.append(i)
    return lst

adress = "255.100.50.0"
tmp = defrang(adress)
x=''
for i in tmp:
    x+=i
print(x)
```

**Second:**

```
adress = "255.100.50.0"
print("[.]".join(adress.split('.')))
```

Which one you think is better? The first doesnt rely on built-in methods but it creates a new list (more memory wasted?)

The second seems better but is it a problem that it relies on built-in methods?

In general idk what level of abstraction is requested by the interviewers, so any advice is welcome (regarding this specific solution or whatever else)

Comment: Using built-in functions is generally good practice and it's really (!) hard to beat their performance with self-written Python code (since they are implemented in C, not Python).

Comment: I'd definitely always create a function and not use the `print` statement from the function, as I/O should be separated.

Comment: Both are bad. You should just use `address.replace('.', '[.]')`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in an interview using Python, assume that the interviewer is
reasonable and wants you to write fluent Python code. That means, among
other things, taking advantage of the language's built-in powers:

```
def defrang(ip):
    return ip.replace('.', '[.]')
```

But let's suppose that the interviewer explicitly directs you to ignore
built-ins and write your own implementation that does the work
character-by-character. Your current implementation is reasonable, but I would
suggest a few things. (1) Especially at interface points (for example, a
function's signature) use substantive variable names when they make sense. (2)
Don't make the caller re-assemble the IP address. (3) There is no need to
use concatenation to create a literal: just use `'[.]'` directly. (4) The logic is
simple enough for a compact if-else expression (this is a stylistic judgment, not a firm opinion).

```
def defang(ip_address):
    chars = []
    for c in ip_address:
        chars.append('[.]' if c == '.' else c)
    return ''.join(chars)
```

A final possibility is to distill further and just use a comprehension.

```
def defang(ip_address):
    return ''.join(
        '[.]' if c == '.' else c 
        for c in ip_address
    )
```